# When paintComponent() is invoked during a repaint process

Tags: java, swing

I'm following the Oracle Swing tutorial per advice from my last post about painting. Now I'm confused as to when and how the paintComponent() method is invoked.

Here's the class:

```
public class MyPanel extends JPanel
{

private int squareX=50;
private int squareY=50;
private int squareW=50;
private int squareH=20;
public MyPanel()
{
    setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));

    addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() { 
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            moveSquare(e.getX(), e.getY());
        }
    });
    addMouseMotionListener(new MouseAdapter(){
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            moveSquare(e.getX(), e.getY());
        }
    });
}

private void moveSquare(int x, int y)
{
    int OFFSET = 1;
    if((squareX!=x)||(squareY!=y))
    {
        repaint(squareX, squareY, squareW+OFFSET, squareH+OFFSET);
        squareX=x;
        squareY=y;
        repaint(squareX, squareY, squareW+OFFSET, squareH+OFFSET);
    }
}

public Dimension getPreferredSize()
{
    return new Dimension(250, 200);
}

protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.drawString("This is my custom panel!", 10, 20);
    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    g.fillRect(squareX, squareY, squareW, squareH);
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.drawRect(squareX, squareY, squareW, squareH);
}
}
```

The tutorial says that both repaint methods are to redraw the previous mouse location as well as the new one. I get that, but where does paintComponent come in? Is it invoked when we say repaint? If so, why doesn't it draw a rectangle in the previous location as well?

Comment: paintComponent is invoked whenever swing needs to do a frame update. This is logic decided internally. You can force it to invoke by calling repaint().

Comment: @HongyuWang: not quite true. You can *suggest* it by calling `repaint()` but that is not a guarantee that it will be called (as per the advanced section of the tutorial), since if repaint requests are "stacked" some will not be called. Also, it is called many times without your request, such as if the OS determines that a section of your GUI contains "dirty pixels".  The main takeaways to get are that:  you do not have full control over when it is called or even if it is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The repaint() method passes the paint request to the `RepaintManager`.

When multiple requests are received in a short period of time the `RepaintManager` will consolidate the two individual requests into a single request to make painting more efficient.

So if you have something like:

```
repaint(5, 5, 20, 20);
...
repaint( 30, 30, 20, 20);
```

The `RepaintManager` ends up consolidating them into a single repaint of `(5, 5, 45, 45)`. This larger area will include the area of both individual requests.

Then the `RepaintManager` will invoke `paint()` on the component which in turn invokes the `paintComponent(...)` method with a clipped area. The `paintCompnent()` method will then paint the background of the clipped area (which will clear the old square from the background) and then paint the square at its new location.

Edit:

The `repaint()` method does not do any painting. `The repaint()` method just invokes the `RepaintManager` suggesting an area of the component that needs to be painted.

1. The first repaint() suggests an area to be painted.
2. The second repaint() suggests another area to be painted.

The `RepaintManager` combines the two smaller areas into one larger area. After a few milliseconds it will then tell the component to repaint itself based on the larger area (this is called the clip bounds). The `paintComponent()` method is only invoked once for each mouse click.

When the `paintComponent(...)` method is invoked:

```
super.paintComponent(g);
```

The above code simply paints the background of the component constrained by the area specified in the clip bounds of the Graphics object. The background color is controlled by the setBackground(...) method.

```
g.drawString("This is my custom panel!", 10, 20);
g.setColor(Color.RED);
g.fillRect(squareX, squareY, squareW, squareH);
g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
g.drawRect(squareX, squareY, squareW, squareH);
```

The above code will then paint the square on top of the cleared background.

Change the painting code to be:

```
super.paintComponent(g);
System.out.println( g.getClipBounds() );
```

and you will see that the actual area of the component that is repainted is the union of the two smaller areas.

Painting a smaller area is theoretically more efficient than painting a larger area. However in reality it is not necessary in this simple example.

Change the code as follows:

```
//repaint(squareX, squareY, squareW+OFFSET, squareH+OFFSET);
squareX=x;
squareY=y;
//repaint(squareX, squareY, squareW+OFFSET, squareH+OFFSET);
repaint();
```

And you will still have the same painting result (with simpler code). Just notice that the clip bounds is now the size of the entire panel no matter where you click.

Comment: So you're saying the paintComponent() will draw specifically at the component (mouse) location, and the 2 repaint()s are just a way of defining the area where the redraw should happen?

Comment: The paintComponent() method will draw the state of your class. It first invokes super.paintComponent() to clear the background. Then it paints the square based on the variables. Normally people would just invoke `repaint()` on the entire panel so the entire background gets cleared and then the square is painted. This example (is more complicated than it needs to be) and is showing how you can make the painting more efficient by showing how to combine the painting of two smaller areas into an area that is still smaller than the panel. It really is unnecessary for something this simple.

Comment: I think I understand now. The first repaint() clears the background(if I comment it out, the squares multiply) because it sees no component (mouse) there, while the second repaint() draws the square because there is a mouse component within the area?

Comment: @B.Wayt, `I think I understand now.` - Not sure. See the edit.